Does adding "there" change the meaning of this sentence?

A: Jack told me that he was going to New York in two weeks. It would be his first time to visit that city.
B: Oh really? It sounds exciting! I’ve heard that there’s a famous steakhouse whose renovation is going to be finished soon. If they reopen it, he can taste their famous sirloin steak______next month.

Does adding "there" in the blank in the last sentence make it sound more like a suggestion of activity that Jack can do in New York?

I would take "there" to refer to the steakhouse, not to New York, so I don't think it would suggest a New York activity.

No, adding there would not have the effect you ask about.

To me, it seems "there" refers to the steakhouse. It's use also seems optional, either would be acceptable.

Why not say "I've heard that there's a famous steakhouse there (i.e. in New York)..." Then you don't need there in the second sentence - it's obvious that you mean 'while he is in NY'.

The entire response by B is predicated on going to New York. It's simple common sense that the steakhouse must be in New York, it's not a language issue at all.

What other thing does the OP think it might mean? Why the question? It's possible to think up strange scenarios where the steakhouse might not be in New York (if New York is famously a place with no steakhouses, but there are lots where A and B are, it may be a suggestion about what Jack can do after his trip). But with the information given, on the balance of probabilities, it's likely to be there.

No. It wouldn't change the meaning. You could add "there" but it's redundant, since we already know that it is about a steak house in New York from the context.

You've asked a lot of questions about whether clauses starting with "if" can constitute suggestions. Presumably you're trying to find the boundaries of when they can do so. I feel like this example is over-complicated; consider something simpler: "Oh, you're going to NY? If you have time you can see the Statue of Liberty." or "If you go to Brooklyn you can walk on the Brooklyn Bridge." or "If it's still playing, you can see Hamilton." Sure, all these are suggestions; that's because of the context (mentioning attractions when someone is planning a trip is understood as recommending them)...

... But it seems funny to single out the word "there" in your example. It doesn't really play a role in the "suggest-ability," or indeed contribute much at all to this example.

Better: It would be his first time visiting the city. not that.

I think it's clear from the context that he would have to visit the steakhouse during his trip to New York. Adding where doesn't really reinforce the statement or qualify it as a suggestion.
Personally, I would add when he's there because that truly clarifies what you mean:

If they reopen it, he can taste their famous sirloin steak when he's there next month.


OP's query:

Does adding "there" in the blank in the last sentence make it sound more like a suggestion of activity that Jack can do in New York?

The sentence is still a suggestion without adding "there". Other modal verbs like should, ought to, could also be used to make suggestions..
All four sentences are suggestions with slight differences in meaning.

If they reopen it, he can taste their famous sirloin steak next month.
If they reopen it, he should taste their famous sirloin steak next month.
If they reopen it, he ought to taste their famous sirloin steak next month.
If they reopen it, he could taste their famous sirloin steak next month.

Modal verb meanings:

Can: implies possibility, and mild suggestion.
Should: implies stronger  advice, or obligation.
Ought to: implies moral or logical obligation,
Could: implies possibility, and mild suggestion (similar to "can").


You missed “must”

@DaleM - I thought  "must" seems like a command or compulsion (not a suggestion)

It is, but the interlocutor could be giving orders (irrespective of if they have the power to or not). In a social situation, people often tell their friends what they must do, even though they have no power to enforce their ‘orders’
